# Abobe Air/Flex 4.6 Remote File Viewer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a Air/Flex desktop application and I'm trying to create a component within the app that can view files on the web server is is already connected to. It just needs to access one particular folder that will contain PDFs, Images & Word documents. I also want the ability to click on the files and having them open in their default desktop applications.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not with your Flex/AIR app alone. It cannot view files/directories on server by itself but it can communicate with your server via webservices, AMF, or any other back end based service. Typically the back end reads the folder and send this information to your app. Your app can open those files in corresponding app but only if those files are available on disk so your app will have to download them prior to opening them.

Comment: Anything is possible with enough programming time!

Answer (score 1):

Every Application has different needs but I myself usually save anything to a desktop or you can use the App storage container as well. As I use only the desktop I download what is needed OR been asked for, and the visitor has the choice of keeping it or if not needed it gets automatically deleted! this way you can use whatever PDFs, Word, Images etc. use read and write (re-write) as well as creating PDFs on the fly with Images, text etc, and that way a visitor also can print directly at his or her own leisure. regards aktell